# Invalid payload - Slack API JSON

Tags: json, groovy

I am using a Groovy script to send a POST using the Slack API, at present I am getting `invalid_payload` returned and I think this is most likely due to the formatting of my JSON. I know the Slack API expects it JSON with double quotes but I can't seem to be able to pass a variable into the JSON object:

```
SUCCESS_MESSAGE = '{"attachments": [{"color": "#2A9B3A", "author_name": ${DEV_NAME}, "title": "Build Status", "title_link": ${BUILD_URL}, "text": "Successful Build" }]}'
def response = ["curl", "-X", "POST", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", "${SUCCESS_MESSAGE}", "https://hooks.slack.com/services/${SLACK_WEBHOOK}"].execute().text
```

How should I correctly format my `SUCCESS_MESSAGE` var so I don't get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to quote your `DEV_NAME` and `BUILD_URL` variable expansions so the JSON string is valid.
2. Your whole string needs to be enclosed in `"` instead of `'` so the variables are actually expanded
3. And you need to `escape` the `"` *inside* your string so they appear in your JSON string.

   SUCCESS_MESSAGE = "{\"attachments\": [{\"color\": \"#2A9B3A\", \"author_name\": \"${DEV_NAME}\", \"title\": \"Build Status\", \"title_link\": \"${BUILD_URL}\", \"text\": \"Successful Build\" }]}"`

Alternatively you can generate the JSON in much nicer programmatic way. Which would be helpful if your notifications got a bit more complicated:

```
def notification = [
  attachments: [
    [
      color: "#2A9B3A",
      author_name: DEV_NAME,
      title: "Build Status",
      title_link: BUILD_URL,
      text: "Successful Build"
    ]
  ]
]

def response = ["curl", "-X", "POST", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", JsonOutput.toJson(notification), "https://hooks.slack.com/services/${SLACK_WEBHOOK}"].execute().text
```

Comment: I have tried that, and all that gets passed through is "${DEV_NAME}" for example and not the actual value

Comment: ah brilliant, that works and thanks for the explanation :-)

Comment: @Richlewis I've also added another way for you to build JSON that can be useful if the notifications get larger and more complicated. You can easily generate them programmatically in Groovy.